# How to access package-protected variable in class I cannot modify

Tags: java

I have a variable that is in a package, where I can neither modify the package or that class and I need to access it is there any way I can do this. I can not modify com.archi.hello or the contents of it

For Example:

com.archi.hello:

class obj:

```
public class obj () { 
    int j = 123;
    int getJ () {
        return j;
    } 
}
```

com.archi.newpackage:

```
public class getJo () { 
    int jo;
    obj obj = new obj();
    jo = obj.getJ(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK BECAUSE THE GETTER IS NOT 
    PUBLIC 
}
```

I need to set jo to j without modifying com.archi.hello in any way, and yes i have tried extending the obj. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Is `j` local or a field? What's its visibility? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Not enough information to help you. You should provide the `visibility scope`, `getter/setter`, class type `Abstract,...`

Comment: it is local just like in the example

Comment: its its exactly like in the example i'm trying to receive it using a getter and the class is a public class

Comment: It has a getter?  Then what's the problem?

Comment: the getter is local it is not a public getter

Comment: It is exactly like the example

Comment: Did you try to `extends` it and then `override getter()`?

Comment: i am not sure how you would do that

Comment: please explain how i would do this

Comment: THIS IS IN THE NEW getJO CLASS: i tried this `@Override int { return getJ; }` but that didn't work

Comment: `class getJo extends obj { @Override int getJ () {
        return NEW_VALUE;
    } }`

Comment: yes, i tried that, the method does not override from super according to android studio.

Comment: This is `Encapsulation priciple` of Java, `getJ() is private method` so I think there is no way to modify it. For example, you cannot change your farther's name or my name because it is mine.

Comment: i dont need to modify it i need to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible cases to get value of `j`: 
Case 1: Because in your example, class `obj` is public and `int j` with default `visibility` => `j` as a public. [Read this about default access modifier](http://codeinventions.blogspot.jp/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html)

```
public class obj () { 
    int j = 123; // not declared modifier => modifier is public because obj class is pulic
    int getJ () { // this method is private
        return j;
    } 
}
```

just do thiss to get value of `j`:

```
obj objInstance = new obj();
int valueOfJ = objInstance.j;
```

Case 2: `private int j` with private access modifier so it is invisible completely with outside. In the `encapsulation priciple` of Java, it not allow to access or modify `j` official way. But, you can use some trick to get value `j`.

```
public class obj () { 
    private int j = 123; // declared modifier => modifier is private
    int getJ () { // this method is private
        return j;
    } 
}
```

How to get `j`

```
obj objInstance = new obj();
java.lang.reflect.Method method = objInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getJ");
method.setAccessible(true);
int valueOfJ = (int)method.invoke(objInstance);
```

Comment: For case 1:  I'm fairly certain that `j` is not public just because the class is public.  Such variables are `package-private`, meaning they can be accessed elsewhere in the package (which doesn't help the asker, because he specified he can't modify anything in the package.)  The reflection thing still works, though.

Comment: Yes, thats why I said there are 2 possible cases ^^!

Comment: I'm just saying that your comment "// not declared modifier => modifier is public because obj class is public" is wrong.  No modifier is package-private.

Comment: Yes `package private` and in example, 2 classes are the same package `com.archi`